# List ordering - Extension method not firing!

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am trying to sort a List like this:

```
public void Example()
{
    string target = "hello";

    List<string> myStings = new List<string>();

    myStings.Add("babab");
    myStings.Add("Helll");
    myStings.Add("atest");

    myStings.OrderBy(each => Distance(each, target));
}

public int Distance(string stringA, string stringB)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

The problem is that the list doesn't get ordered and the Distance method doesn't get fired (I put a breakpoint in there but doesn't get hit).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of **[Linq's Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)**

> In LINQ, execution of a query is
>   usually deferred until the moment when
>   you actually request the data.

So, to see your method working, apply the `ToList()` method to your `IOrderedEnumerable` so that you will **actually be requesting the data**, and thus the execution takes place.

```
myStings = myStings.OrderBy(each => Distance(each, target)).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution forces the deferred execution so that distance will be called but myStrings still won't be sorted.

Comment: Yes, that's true; I was only forcing the execution.  I have updated the answer so that the returned sorted list is stored

Answer (score 1):

myStings = myStings.OrderBy(each => Distance(each, target)).ToList();

Comment: The String.Replace thing is because strings are immutable

Comment: there's a similarity in form though (even if the reason is not the same)

Answer (score 1):

your

```
myStrings.OrderBy(each => Distance(each, target));
```

wont order your original list it return a ordered list.
You need:

```
myStrings = myStrings.OrderBy(each => Distance(each, target)).ToList();
```

this will force the deferred execution to take place and give you the result you require.